# how to disable days in bootstrap date time picker?

Tags: datetimepicker

I am using this datetime picker,
https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/,
can anyone please help me how can i disable the specific days from calender.

Answer (score 0):

Use this fork of [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

To disable specific dates try,

```
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                disabledDates: [
                    moment("12/25/2013")                        
                ]
            });
        });
```

[Source](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates)